# Google sheet arrayformula join() and split() functions

Tags: google-sheets

Does anybody know how to arrayformula this `join` function?

My formula is not as complex as the example here. [ArrayFormula a Filter in a Join (Google Spreadsheets)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433945/how-do-i-convert-this-formula-into-an-arrayformula-google-spreadsheets)

It does not contain a `filter` function, so I'm not sure what from that answer applies and doesn't apply.

I want to array formula this: `=if(isblank(B2),,join("," ,B2:I2))`

Using the normal way to array something doesn't work:

`=ArrayFormula(if(isblank(B2:b),,join(",",B2:b:I2:i)))`

Also for splits, I have `split(B2, ",")`

`=ArrayFormula(split(B2:B,","))` does nothing but the first row

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe try:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(B2:B), B2:B&C2:C&D2:D&E2:E&F2:F&G2:G&H2:H&I2:I,))
```

or

```
=ArrayFormula(substitute(transpose(query(transpose(B2:I),,rows(B2:B)))," ",""))
```

or, in case you want a space between the concatenated values:

```
=ArrayFormula(trim(transpose(query(transpose(B2:I),,rows(B2:B)))))
```

For using split() in arrayformula a workaround can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137115/arrayformula-does-not-work-wirth-split)

Comment: very nice solution with query. I think, `COLUMNS(B2:I)` instead of `rows(B2:B)` would be more accurate.