# trying to split within arrayformula inside google spreadsheet

Tags: regex, split, google-sheets, formulas

I am trying to use the split function within the ARRAYFORMULA function inside a google spreadsheet.

I want "**1.2.3.4**" to become "**1**", "**2**", "**3**", "**4**"

This is the code for a one-liner (working for 1 row only):

```
=SPLIT(A2;".")
```

This is what I want to achieve (to work on multiple rows at the same time):

```
//alone
=SPLIT(A2:A;".")

//or with ARRAYFORMULA
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(A2:A;"."))
```

Since the SPLIT function can't be used within the ARRAYFORMULA function, I searched for a workaround ([ARRAYFORMULA() does not work with SPLIT()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137115/arrayformula-does-not-work-wirth-split)):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT("."&A2:A;"^"&REPT(".+[^.]+";COLUMN(OFFSET(A2;;;1;4))-1)&".+([^.]+)")))
```

It's almost working except for the fact that it doesnt split correctly, here is the result I get:

"1.2.3.4" becomes "4", "4", "4", "4"

If I can get the workaround to actually work correctly or a better alternative that would be more than awesome...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ARRAYFORMULA() does not work wirth SPLIT()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137115/arrayformula-does-not-work-wirth-split)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your expression creates regular expressions like this:

```
^.+[^.]+.+[^.]+.+[^.]+.+([^.]+)
```

The `.+` part will match anything, as much as possible, thus pushing he last `([^.]+)` to the end.

If you use an expression like this instead, it should work better:

```
^\.[^.]*\.[^.]*\.[^.]*\.([^.]*)
```

It will always count each `.`, and never push the last group too far.

(You could use `{3}` instead of repeating the subpattern, but that would change your original formula too much)

Here is the corresponding formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT("."&A2:A;
    "^"&REPT("\.[^.]*";COLUMN(OFFSET(A2;;;1;4))-1)&"\.([^.]*)")))
```

Comment: would you be able to provide example. 

ARRAYFORMULA(...) mentioned above doesn't work

CHeers

Answer (score -2):

you could try this:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\.","\"",\""")
```

UPDATE: Google fixed this and you can now use arrayformula with split:

`=ArrayFormula(SPLIT(Sheet1!A2:A,"."))`

Comment: Although the proposed formula works as an array formula, for `1.2.3.4` it returns `1","2","3","4` instead of the values splited by the delimiter (dot).