# Fix for ARRAYFORMULA() SPLIT()

Tags: google-sheets

I have cells with data like this (all in the same cell)

```
Lender: ASB, Limit: 45345, Balance: 34534
Lender: BNZ, Limit: 5435, Balance: 345
```

This formula achieves the outcome that I am after; it separates the data by comma and then by line into one row:

```
=SPLIT(join(",",SPLIT(substitute(A2," ",""),Char(10))),",")
```

However, I need this to work as an array, something like:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A2:A="","",SPLIT(join(",",SPLIT(substitute(A2:A," ",""),Char(10))),",")))
```

I have read this [ARRAYFORMULA() does not work with SPLIT()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137115/arrayformula-does-not-work-wirth-split) and can't come up with a working solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Adam's formula works fine. All you needed is to replace Char(10): `=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(","&SUBSTITUTE(A1:A,char(10),","),"^"&REPT(",+[^,]+",COLUMN(OFFSET(A1,,,1,6))-1)&",+([^,]+)")))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this (pretending your original data is in column B):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(","&REGEXREPLACE(B2:B,"\n",","),"^"&REPT("\,[^,]*",COLUMN(OFFSET(A1,,,1,6))-1)&"\,([^,]*)")))
```

Comment: Genius!!  Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem! Btw If my answer solved your problem can you please  accept the answer when you get a chance?

Comment: Ahhh right.  Sorry.  New to this.  Thanks so much for your time :D