# How can I separate a string by underscore (_) in google spreadsheets using regex?

Tags: regex, string, google-sheets

I need to create some columns from a cell that contains text separated by "_".

The input would be:
campaign1_attribute1_whatever_yes_123421

And the output has to be in different columns (one per field), with no "_" and excluding the final number, as it follows:
campaign1 attribute1 whatever yes

It **must** be done using a regex formula!

help!

Thanks in advance (and sorry for my english)

Comment: The answer to this Q was here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137115/arrayformula-does-not-work-with-split

Answer (score 1):

To solve this you can use the SPLIT and REGEXREPLACE functions

Solution:

```
Text      -  A1 = "campaign1_attribute1_whatever_yes_123421"
Formula   -  A3 = =SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"_+\d*$",""), "_", TRUE)
```

Explanation:

In cell A3 We use SPLIT(text, delimiter, [split_by_each]), the text in this case is formatted with regex *=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"_+\d*$","")* to remove *123421, witch will give you a column for each word delimited by "*"

```
A1 = "campaign1_attribute1_whatever_yes_123421"
A2 = "=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"_+\d*$","")" //This gives you : *campaign1_attribute1_whatever_yes*
A3 = SPLIT(A2, "_", TRUE) //This gives you: campaign1 attribute1 whatever yes, each in a separate column.
```

Comment: Please provide some sort of explanation or narrative about your answer. Even if it may be correct, just a straight answer like this is often useless.

Answer (score 1):

`=REGEXEXTRACT("campaign1_attribute1_whatever_yes_123421","(("&REGEXREPLACE("campaign1_attribute1_whatever_yes_123421","((_)|(\d+$))",")$1(")&"))")`

What this does is replace all the `_` with parenthesis to create capture groups, while also excluding the digit string at the end, then surround the whole string with parenthesis.

[image]

We then use regex extract to actuall pull the pieces out, the groups automatically push them to their own cells/columns

[image]

Comment: to convert it into arrayFormula: `=ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A13,"(("&REGEXREPLACE(A1:A13,"((_)|(\d+$))",")$1(")&"))"))`

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out yesterday in stackoverflow (spanish): https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/55362/c%C3%B3mo-separo-texto-por-guiones-bajos-de-una-celda-en...

It was simple enough after all...

The reason I asked to be only in regex and for google sheets was because I need to use it in Google data studio (same regex functions than spreadsheets)

To get each column just use this regex extract function:

1st column: `REGEXP_EXTRACT(Campaña, '^(?:[^_]*_){0}([^_]*)_')`

2nd column: `REGEXP_EXTRACT(Campaña, '^(?:[^_]*_){1}([^_]*)_')`

3rd column: `REGEXP_EXTRACT(Campaña, '^(?:[^_]*_){2}([^_]*)_')`

etc...
The only thing that has to be changed in the formula to switch columns is the numer inside {}, (column number - 1).
If you do not have the final number, just don't put the last "_".

Lastly, remember to do all the calculated fields again, because (for example) it gets an error with CPC, CTR and other Adwords metrics that are calculated automatically.

Hope it helps!