# Google Sheets: Regexextract

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using google sheets and the `REGEXEXTRACT` formula to extract all letters/numbers/hyphens in a range. In the examples below, I'm looking to remove the apostrophes.

'02 Blue Twisters

Blue Twisters '02

Blue Twisters 02-03

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(DN3:DN="","",REGEXEXTRACT(DN3:DN,"\w+\w+\w+")))`
`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(DN3:DN="","",REGEXEXTRACT(DN3:DN,"w.+")))`
`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(DN3:DN="","",REGEXEXTRACT(DN3:DN,"w+")))`
`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(DN3:DN="","",REGEXEXTRACT(DN3:DN,"[a-zA-Z0-9].+)))`
`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(DN3:DN="","",REGEXEXTRACT(DN3:DN,"[a-zA-Z0-9]+")))`

`\w+` seems work as intended [HERE](https://regexr.com/) but they don't seem to do the trick in Google Sheets. Some remove that first apostrophe, but not interior ones. Some don't remove anything.

Any ideas as to what I may be missing

Comment: Although I'm not sure about the detail output you want, when you want to remove the apostrophes from the values, for example, how about using ``REGEXREPLACE()`` like ``=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(DN3:DN="","",REGEXREPLACE(A:A,"'","")))``? If I misunderstand your question, can you provide the sample output values you want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is REGEXEXTRACT returning a single value when it is expected to return an array of 1 row and multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42826011/why-is-regexextract-returning-a-single-value-when-it-is-expected-to-return-an-ar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help folks, I came across two solutions. They're a bit complex but work.

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("(",H3:H))=TRUE,TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(H3:H,"\(|\)","")),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("'",H3:H))=TRUE,TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(H3:H,"'","")),H3:H)))`

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(DN3:DN="","",TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(DN3:DN,"("," "),")"," "),"'"," "),":"," "),";"," "),"!"," "),","," "),"."," "))))`

Answer (score 1):

> Any ideas as to what I may be missing

[SUBSTITUTE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215).

Answer (score 0):

> extract all letters/numbers/hyphens in a range.

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A2, "[^A-Za-z0-9-]",)
```