# How to use CONCAT in QUERY?

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a table:

```
 A     |   B      |     C
BEN    |  MOSKOW  |    YES
ANTON  |  IRKUTSK |     NO
VIKTOR |  PARIS   |    YES
BEN    |  PARIS   |    YES
ANTON  |  TORONTO |     NO
DON    | TORONTO  |    YES
ANNA   | IRKUTSK  |    YES
BEN    |  MOSKOW  |     NO
```

and tried a formula:

```
=UNIQUE(query(A:C; "Select A,B,C where A contains 'BEN' OR A contains 'ANTON' order by A"))
```

and an arrayformula:

```
=arrayformula(UNIQUE(query(A:C; "Select A,B,C where A contains 'BEN' OR A contains 'ANTON' order by A")))
```

but the results are in columns:

```
ANTON  |  IRKUTSK |     NO
ANTON  |  TORONTO |     NO
BEN    |  MOSKOW  |    YES
BEN    |  PARIS   |    YES
BEN    |  MOSKOW  |     NO
```

whereas I need results in only one cell per row, like so:

```
ANTON IRKUTSK NO
ANTON TORONTO NO
BEN MOSCOW YES
BEN PARIS YES
BEN MOSKOW NO
```

Comment: u can use CONCATENATE(A," ", B)

Comment: `=UNIQUE(query(A:C; "Select CONCATENATE(A," ", B," ", C) where A contains 'BEN' OR A contains 'ANTON' order by A"))` not work

Comment: There is CONCAT in sheets, but not in Google Query, which is what the question is

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Transpose twice.

```
=transpose(query(transpose(_you query_);;COLUMNS(_you query_)))
```

For an example from my question:

```
=transpose(query(transpose(UNIQUE(query(A:C; "select * where A contains 'BEN' OR A contains 'ANTON' order by A")));;COLUMNS(UNIQUE(query(A:C; "select * where A contains 'BEN' OR A contains 'ANTON' order by A")))))
```

Result:

```
ANTON IRKUTSK NO
ANTON TORONTO NO
BEN MOSCOW YES
BEN PARIS YES
BEN MOSKOW NO
```

Comment: this is a super handy trick, thank you

Answer (score 15):

There is no `concat` option in Google Sheets `query`.

Workaround, suggested by JPV may fit you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29799384/5372400

use formula:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(
SUBSTITUTE(
trim(transpose(query(transpose(_your_query_here_),,COLUMNS(_your_query_here_))))," "," → ")
)`

Change `" → "` to space `" "` to concat the result with space.

---

More info about SQL in Sheets:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage