# Concatenating Text

Tags: google-sheets, string-concatenation

I need to concatenate text from various cells to a single cell in a row. This can go to an infinite number of rows.

How to use the CONCATENATE function in Google Sheets for doing this?

I also need to know how to use "if else if" in Google Sheets. For example:

```
IF(A2="This")
JOIN(" ", A2,B2)
ELSE IF(A2="I")
JOIN(" ",A2,C2)
ELSE IF(A2="value")
JOIN(" ",A2,D2)
```

Is this possible in Google Sheets?

[image: Concatenate Text From several cells into a single cell]

Comment: please check this link [link](https://www.thoughtco.com/concatenate-text-data-in-google-spreadsheets-3123801)

Comment: @MaddyNikam I have edited my question according to my actual requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use jon function:

`=join(" ", a2:e2)`

You may also like this arrayFormula solution:

[Google sheet arrayformula join() and split() functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236241/google-sheet-arrayformula-join-and-split-functions)

Comment: I also need to know if I can give a condition like this:
IF(CONDITION)
ELSE IF(CONDITION)
ELSE

Comment: Is it possible to use if else if?

Comment: I guess so, why are you asking this in a comment, not in Q? You may edit the Q and show what final result you want.

Answer (score 0):

to merge text:

=CONCATENATE(A1;" ";B1;" ";C1;" ";D1;" ";E1)

And yes you can use CONCATENATE in IF formula.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
if(A2="This",JOIN(" ", A2,B2),IF(A2="I",JOIN(" ",A2,C2),IF(A2="value"),JOIN(" ",A2,D2),"Else Value")))
```

Syntax
`IF(logical_expression, value_if_true, value_if_false)`

you can refer these links

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/CmebALbskuo

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en